# Contractions in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $T:E \mapsto E$ a contraction. Is it true that for every $z \in E$ there exists an unique element $u \in E$ such that $(T-I)(u)=z$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The operator $\tilde{T}u=Tu-z$ is a contraction. So the equation $\tilde{T}u=u$ has exactly one solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that $T$ is also supposed to be linear.
The space of continuous linear endomorphisms of $E$, denoted as $\mathcal{L}(E)$ is a Banach algebra with the classic norm :
$$\|T\| = \sup_{\|x \| \leq 1} \|T(x)\|$$
Since $T$ is a contraction, it is continuous with $\|T\| < 1$.
Now consider the equality, that holds for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ : 
$$\left(I+T+T^2+...+T^n\right)(I-T)=(I-T)\left(I+T+T^2+...+T^n\right)=I-T^{n+1}$$
Since $\|T^{n}\| \leq \|T\|^n$ (Banach algebras inequality), the right hand converges to $I$.

Furthermore, the series $S_n:=\left(I+T+T^2+...+T^n\right)$ is normally convergent, hence convergent to a limit $S$ in the Banach algebra $\mathcal{L}(E)$.
Finally, by continuity of the product in a Banach algebra, you get :
$$S(I-T)=(I-T)S=I$$
Therefore $I-T$ is invertible which is what we wanted to prove.